# Phrase for getting distracted by other things and turning away from the true purpose

Tags: phrases, idioms

I apologise in advance for the rather confusing title as I’m having a hard time wording it. I’m looking for an idiom which suits the statement below

> The public has been focused on pressuring the judiciary to be more diverse but they are getting carried away from the true purpose of the judiciary

Is there any idioms that denotes something like this “where people are focusing too much on the other aspect that it defeats the purpose of the existence of something in the first place?”

Comment: They are (in my opinion) losing sight of the primary purpose of the judiciary.

Comment: Are you wanting something quite formal? There are various colorful informal expressions but if you're writing about the judiciary you are probably in a higher register.

Comment: They're getting ***distracted***, not ***carried away*** (which latter is a metaphorical expression meaning ***enthusiastically affected by and participating in*** in this context).

Comment: The public has been focused on pressuring the judiciary to be more diverse but they are **straying from their true purpose**.

Answer (score 0):

Both "**(to) digress**" and "**(go) off topic**" appear under idioms on "The Free Dictionary".

> The public has been focused on pressuring the judiciary to be more
> diverse but they "***digressed/went off topic***" from the true
> purpose of the judiciary

[TFD - digress](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/digress)

[TFD - idiom - off topic](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Off+topic)